# refresh uitable of a viewcontroller from other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, uitableview, uitabbarcontroller

I have a uitable in one of the Tabview of a tabbarcontroller application. Now depending on some action in other tabview, the uitable should reload (refresh) for updated data at backgrouns. However, I am not able to get it using either reloadData or beginupdates-endUpdates.

Can someone please help in this kind of scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you are new on this forum so a piece of advice - after you post your question, you should visit back and either accept or vote up or down. Feedback is IMPORTANT.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend use a combination of NSNotification as well as viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear for this.

When the viewWillAppear - reload the tableview (You may refine it by looking for change in data since you last time displayed the data)

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Your other code here...
    [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

Once the view has appeared and in background the data is changed by some other object - ask that object to send notification and in your tableview's viewcontroller register for that notificaiton in viewWillAppear & deregister in viewWillDisappear

The *other* object should send/post notification like this (just after the data change)-

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"com.yourcompany.appname.XYZdataChangeNotification" object:nil];
```

All the below code in your viewController (which has table to be updated) -

Register like this -

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    // Your other code here...
    [self.tableview reloadData];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleNewDataReceivedNotification:) name:@"com.yourcompany.appname.XYZdataChangeNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Notification handler in your view controller -

```
- (void)handleNewDataReceivedNotification:(NSNotification *)notification
{
        // Your other code here...
        [self.tableview reloadData];
}
```

And de-register like this -

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:@"com.yourcompany.appname.XYZdataChangeNotification" object:nil];

}
```

All the above code can be refined but it should give you an idea. Please feel free to ask if any questions/concerns.